# angular.js:13550 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /PURNATEST/App/Reports/ABC/ReportEditModel.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am using a webapi SPA application with angular UI. I am loading a html page using the templateurl like below

```
 $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/PURNATEST/App/Reports/ABC/ReportEditModel.html',
        controller: 'ABCDController',
        scope: $scope
    }).result.then(function ($scope) {
        clearSearch();
    }, function () {
        var stest = "";
    });
```

I am getting the below error :
angular.js:13550 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /PURNATEST/App/Reports/ABC/ReportEditModel.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

In BundleConfig I am registering the both bootstrap and bootstrap-tpl

```
"~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js",// used
"~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js", //used
```

And my module looks like this

```
 var PCMApp = angular.module('PCMApp', [       
    'ngRoute',          //app route (url path) support
    'ngSanitize',       //fixes HTML issues in data binding        
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngDialog',        
    'common'       
]);
```

Can any one let me know how to proceed to resolve this issue.?

Comment: error says `404` File not found, you sure that file does exist on `/PURNATEST/App/Reports/ABC/ReportEditModel.html` this location?

Comment: Yes Pankaj, I crossverified . It exists.

Comment: Make sure that you give the correct path to `templateUrl`.

Comment: I tried with giving the full url ( absolute url ) too. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved, i was using a provider hosted app for sharepoint and the filepaths are different while debugging(dev env) and test environment ( after deployment ). The issue was with the relative paths .

Thanks for the replies.
-PURNA